# IBOutlets/actions and custom subview

Tags: ios, uiview, subview, ibaction

Apologies if this seems a straightforward question! I'm using `AVFoundation` to build a custom camera app that allows the user to draw on the image after it's taken (similar to snapchat).

I have the camera functionality working. Currently, after the shutter button is pressed I add (as a subview) a standard `UIImageView` to display the photo taken. Seeing as I want there to be custom options at this stage (including drawing on the image), I proceeded to create my own subclass of `UIImageView`. I am designing this view in Interface Builder (xib file).

Say for instance I have a button on this custom view, that when pressed, simply deletes the image and takes me back to the camera view to take another image. Can I handle the `IBActions` for this custom view within the `ViewController` for my camera view? Is this bad practice?

Any guidance on how best to implement this would be really appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest putting the button on your custom view.

I would have the `UIViewController` display the custom view and also give display a button for your action. Most likely the `UIViewController` will want to display a `UIToolBar` at the bottom of the screen which will allow for multiple buttons/actions, but that's up to you.

But why do I say this? Compartmentalization. Your custom view has no need or use for the button. It's meaningless to what your doing... displaying the image. Your custom view will also probably be used in many locations, several of which won't want this button displayed. Even if your custom view had the button it wouldn't know what to do if someone tapped it. It would then have to pass that interaction off the view controller which cares about the action and and handle it. Your custom view will mostly likely have public methods allowing other code to give it directions (like clear or undo).

Depending on the say things go, you may decide you want a custom `UIViewController` which handles interactions on your custom view. Then any other view controllers could just add it in as a containerized view controller and you could have the same functionality with no code duplication at several places in your applications.